# Changing server state with GET?

Tags: api, rest

OK, I know this is bad. As a rule, GET requests should be for read-only queries; they should not change the state of the server and its data. But how I can handle the next situation?

A client must fetch all the "chat rooms" near to him. This typically may be something like `GET /chatrooms?lat=x&lng=y`. But, if there are no chatrooms near to him, then a room must be automatically created. Of course this can be achieved doing `POST /chartrooms`.

But this implies 2 requests to the server and I want just to do one: a `GET /chatrooms?lat=x&lng=y`and then if there are no rooms, in the server create a new one and return it to the client. So `GET` must change, sometimes, the state in the server (create a new room)

The server side would be something like this (pseudo-code):

```
@GET /chatrooms
List<ChatRoom> getAll():
    lat = getQuery("lat")
    lng = getQuery("lng")
    chatRooms[] = findChatRoomsByLatLng(lat, lng)
    if (chatRooms.size > 0): // This is the normal GET
       return json(chatRooms, 200)
    else   // In this case GET change the server state
       chatRoom = new ChatRoom(lat, lng)
       saveChatRoom(chatRoom)
       return json(chatRoom, 200)
```

That is my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're referring to the idea of GET as a "safe method". Being "safe" doesn't mean "can't change server state". It means "can't be used *by the client* to request a change in server state". In your case, the change is clearly done by the server and is totally invisible to the user. This is in line with the last paragraph from the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-9.1.1), quoted below. I see no problem with you using the GET to create the relevant chat room if none exists.

> Section 9.1.1 Safe Methods

> Implementors should be aware that the software represents the user in
> their interactions over the Internet, and should be careful to allow
> the user to be aware of any actions they might take which may have an
> unexpected significance to themselves or others.

> In particular, the convention has been established that the GET and
> HEAD methods SHOULD NOT have the significance of taking an action
> other than retrieval. These methods ought to be considered "safe".
> This allows user agents to represent other methods, such as POST, PUT
> and DELETE, in a special way, so that the user is made aware of the
> fact that a possibly unsafe action is being requested.

> Naturally, it is not possible to ensure that the server does not
> generate side-effects as a result of performing a GET request; in
> fact, some dynamic resources consider that a feature. The important
> distinction here is that the user did not request the side-effects,
> so therefore cannot be held accountable for them.

Answer (score 1):

If a room is requested which does not exists, simply create the room and return it. The client should not even notice this. GET is ok for that.

Its just like dynamically generated images, like thumbnails or whatever. Would you send two requests to download a dynamically generated image? I would not do so.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds reasonable to me.